# Program is crashing from creating push function for Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

I am trying to implement a stack using a Linked List. My program keeps crashing and when trying to print the new Linked List, it prints an unsigned integer. My print function works fine, so it is this function below.

Please help.

```
void LinkedList::Push (int val)
{
    Node* newHead = new Node;
    Node* oldHead = new Node;
    newHead->value = val;
    oldHead = head;
    head = newHead;
    oldHead->prev = head;
    head->next = oldHead;
    delete newHead;
}
```

Comment: what is `head`?  At any rate, you've got a memory leak because `oldHead` never gets `delete`d

Comment: You *do* know that [std::stack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) already exists, right?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I think OP is trying to implement a linked list, not a stack.  But I'm guessing this is a homework assignment anyway so that would be why they are "reinventing the wheel".

Comment: I assume you are trying to `push_front`: `new_node->next = head; head = new_node;`

Comment: @BenJones Could be. Impossible to tell from the question as written.

Comment: You have a memory leak:  `oldHead = head;`.  BTW, you don't need to allocate objects in order to use a pointer.

Comment: Here is two of your bugs: `Node* oldHead = new Node;` and `delete newHead;` The first causes a memory leak since you do `oldHead = head;` The second frees memory that is used inside your list after the node has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that the `Node` that you've `new`ed in the definition of `oldHead` is never `delete`d.  Since you set `oldHead` to `head` immediately after creating it, I would suggest this as your definition:

```
Node* oldHead = head;
```

The **main issue**, though, is that you `delete` `newHead`, which is now what `head` points to. Therefore, when you go to print `head`, you are reading invalid data.

I would highly recommend leaving the resource handling to objects like [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead of `new`ing and `delete`ing yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your question.

Your fixed method:

```
void Push( const int val )
{
  Node* newNode { new Node };
  newNode->value = val;
  newNode->next = head;
  head = newNode;
}
```

Read more about Linked List operations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Linked_list_operations). You do not need a doubly linked list to implement a stack - you only need to push/pop at one end.

**[EDIT]**

I didn't notice you are using a doubly linked list (this is why a complete/verifiable example is required). As I said, for a stack implementation, a singly linked list is enough.